Is there any way to override bazelrc location without changing command line?
I'm trying to integrate bazel into a Linux distro packaging system.
Since bazel does not interpret commonly-used environment variables like $CFLAGS, and since its sandbox interferes with wrappers such as ccache/distcc, I find myself in need to pass numerous command-line options to bazel.
To keep command-lines short, and to keep it transparent wrt. existing bazel calls in build scripts, I decided that it would be better to write those autogenerated command-line options to bazelrc, which will be then read automatically.

However, I would like to avoid clobbering ~/.bazelrc or /etc/bazel.bazelrc. As such, is there any way to control the location of bazelrc file using an environment variable or any other method transparent to the bazel invocation (i.e. without changing the command line)?

try-import could help. You could try-import a symlink path (or multiple) and override the symlink when you want to change the file it points to.
Another option which might solve your problem sufficiently concisely is to pass --bazelrc=foo.bazelrc or --bazelrc=bar.bazelrc, depending on some condition. That way you can change just one parameter and transparently add groups of options.
However, this sounds like --config=foo and --config=bar though, which is a nicer solution. A --config=foo|bar|baz definition is the most idiomatic way to solve this.

This implies that I modify any of the bazelrc files. I want to do this without modifying either the project or the bazel invocation, in a completely ambient manner (i.e. just how $CFLAGS work in every other build system).

I don't think it's possible to do this with an env variable. I think you're going to have to either edit the bazelrc file(s) (at least once) or change the command line. You could keep the "same" command line by doing something like bazel build $BZL_FLAGS //targets, but I think that's as close as you can get.
